# Visual Studio 2013 Pro README.md in solution root

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, readme

In Visual Studio 2013 Pro, is there a way to have a README.md for the root solution? We have a rather large solution and I'm trying to create a main README.md that can give an intro of each of the projects and a link to their READMEs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know this was asked a few months ago, but in case people find this question as I did, I'm giving my answer. You can right-click the solution, click `Add`, `New Item...`, and then create a text file called `README.md`. It will create the file in a folder called "Solutions Items" in the Solution Explorer, but that folder would not be created in your project file structure. So it is like a logical folder only.

Also, it seems that if you clone or fork a project that already has a `README.md` file for the solution, VS2013 does not automatically display it in the Solution Explorer. You have to include it there through `Add`, `Existing Item...`.